# JavaScript - Make selection bold in contentEditable div without execCommand() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg

I am making wysiwyg editor, but I won't use `execCommand()` function and I have got problem with effects like bold and italic. Below is my code. If you try to bold only underlined or strikethroughed it will works, but if you try to bold text with two styles (like underline and strikethrough) there is an error. How can I repair it?
Thanks for help.

```js
$('#BoldButton').click(function ()
    {
        var elem = AddClassToSelected('bold');
        
        //Chceck if inside created <span> isn't another <span> with bold class. If it is removed it.
        $(elem).children().each(function (event) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('bold')) {
                $(this).replaceWith($(this).contents());
            }
        });
    });
    
function AddClassToSelected(newClass){
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = newClass;

    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(span);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }

    return span;
}
```

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="BoldButton">Bold</button>
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
    <u>SomeTextSomeText</u><strike>SomeTextSomeText</strike>
</div>
```